# I keep getting a name error code but I already have defined the name twice in function I cant seem to find the error

Tags: nameerror

I keep getting a name error code but I already have defined the name twice in function and I can't seem to find the error. Here's the code:

```
firstword = input("Enter phrase: ")
secondword = input("Enter phrase: ")

def get_phrase(sorted_fw, sorted_sw) :
    sorted_fw = sorted(firstword.lower())
    sorted_sw = sorted(secondword.lower())

if sorted_fw == sorted_sw :
    print ("The phrases are anagrams.")
else:
    print("The phrases are not anagrams.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nameerror as the literals sorted_fw, sorted_sw are defined inside the function and their scope is limited to the function. Also to return sorted version of both the phrases you should provide a return statement that returns the sorted strings. You can modify the code as shown here:

```
firstword = input("Enter phrase: ")
secondword = input("Enter phrase: ")

def get_phrase(sorted_fw, sorted_sw) :
    sorted_fw = ''.join(sorted(firstword.lower()))
    sorted_sw = ''.join(sorted(secondword.lower()))
    return sorted_fw, sorted_sw

firstword, secondword = get_phrase(firstword, secondword)

if firstword == secondword :
    print ("The phrases are anagrams.")
else:
    print("The phrases are not anagrams.")
```

There is a more simpler way if you just want to sort the strings without using other variables. You can write:

```
firstword = input("Enter phrase: ")
secondword = input("Enter phrase: ")

def get_phrase() :
    global firstword, secondword
    firstword = ''.join(sorted(firstword.lower()))
    secondword = ''.join(sorted(secondword.lower()))

get_phrase()

if firstword == secondword :
    print ("The phrases are anagrams.")
else:
    print("The phrases are not anagrams.")
```

In fact you don't need to use 'join' also as in that case sorted function will return the lists and comparison will take place between the sorted lists, which will give the same result.